# Java EAR with multiple Beans using JPA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I have an EAR application that will be using several modules.

The structure is as follows:

```
app - Modules - EJB 1
              - MDB 1
              - MDB 2
              - EJB 2
```

As you can see the EAR has several different Modules that are all different types of beans.

There is one database that is being connected to and modified with JPA.

Each module requires access to this database with JPA.

Is it good practice to have one EJB that contains the Entity classes and some manager classes which then expose a local interface that the other Modules can access. The other modules could then call this one EJB to do all the searches, inserts etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is the [data access object](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html) pattern.  I don't believe it's very relevant with JPA, since the `EntityManager` is effectively already a DAO, so adding your own doesn't add much benefit.

I'd suggest it is worth considering if you have complex access patterns to your entities which you would like to encapsulate.  If your entities are all accessed in standard ways which don't require additional action, then I'd leave it to the `EntityManager`.